# Consistency strength of the Large cardinals is almost linear

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Is there a known and strong reason why the large cardinal hierarchy is almost linear w.r.t.
the consistency strength?

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly regarded as open (that is, nobody truly knows why this is). Hugh Woodin's $\Omega$-logic program (an infinitary logic with important properties) hopes to solve this and perhaps even give a platonic "answer" to the Continuum Hypothesis.

You can read about in the links mentioned on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-logic#Analysis) page, however it is still a controversial matter as to whether it resolves anything. The essential idea is that there is a notion called $\Omega$-provability which allows us to create a quite general definition of a large-cardinal axiom. It then shows that there is a sort of proof-hierarchy in set theory so that the large cardinals each correspond nicely with each rank...

Apologies if this answer is quite vague - this is quite cutting-edge stuff!

Comment: My understanding is that the $\Omega$-logic approach to CH has been largely discredited by work of Sargsyan - see the comments [to this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/25179/8133).

Comment: Yes, I've heard in fact that Woodin has stopped speaking about it altogether... Thanks for the link!